# Declare NamedStoredProcedureQuery without Entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I am working with Hibernate and would like to use some NamedStoredProcedureQueries annotations with custom ResultMapping, i.e.

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
    name = SP_NAME,
    procedureName = SP_NAME,
    resultSetMappings = {},
    parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = BigDecimal.class, name = PARAM)
    }
)
```

The Problem ist now that the @NamedStoredProcedureQuery annotation will only be processed if put into an entity.

But in this case, I dont have (and want) an entity because there is no result mapping neccessary and also dont have an ID to put the @Id annotation on.

Is there another way to declare NamedStoredProcedureQueries without using entities?

Comment: Like putting it in `orm.xml` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other way using that annotation.

> Specifies multiple named stored procedure queries. Query names are
>   scoped to the persistence unit. The NamedStoredProcedureQueries
>   annotation can be applied to an entity or mapped superclass.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/NamedStoredProcedureQueries.html

You can call SP programmatically.